# Perl Import large .csv to MySQL, don't repeat data

Tags: mysql, perl, csv

I am trying to import several .csv files into a mysql database, the script below works except that it only imports the first row of my csv data into the database. Both my tables are populated with exactly one data entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use strict;
use warnings;

# MySQL CONFIG VARIABLES
my $host = "localhost";
my $user = "someuser";
my $pw = "somepassword";

my $database = "test";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=" . $database . ";host=" . $host;

 my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw)
   or die "Can't connect to the DB: $DBI::errstr\n";

 print "Connected to DB!\n";


# enter the file name that you want import

my $filename = "/home/jonathan/dep/csv/linux_datetime_test_4.26.13_.csv";

open FILE, "<", $filename or die $!;

$_ = <FILE>;
$_ = <FILE>;

while (<FILE>) {
   my @f = split(/,/,$_);

if (length($f[4]) < 10) {
            print "No Weight\n"; 
    }
    else {
           #insert the data into the db
           print "insert into datetime_stamp\n"; 
}
        my $sql = "INSERT INTO datetime_stamp (subject, date, time, weight)                       
VALUES('$f[1]', '$f[2]', '$f[3]', '$f[4]')";
    print "$sql\n";
        my $query = $dbh->do($sql);

        my $sql = "INSERT INTO subj_weight (subject, weight) VALUES('$f[1]', '$f[2]')";
        my $query = $dbh->do($sql);

close(FILE);
}
```

Comment: put the `close(FILE)` outside the `while` loop

Comment: This isn't going to work as you expect without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/perl).

Comment: @tadman: It is quite likely that escaping is unnecessary if the data is simple. Certainly the table names don't need it, which is what your link describes.

Comment: There's no such thing as "simple". A `subject` of `O'Reilly` would make the query fail. You **must** properly escape anything you put into your SQL statement. Assumptions only get you into severe trouble. That link talks about how to safely escape both table names and values using `?` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

As has been commented, you close the input file after reading the first data entry, and so only populate your database with a single record.

However there are a few problems with your code you may want to consider:

- You should set `autoflush` on the `STDOUT` file handle if you are printing diagnostics as the program runs. Otherwise perl won't print the output until either it has a buffer full of text to print or the file handle is closed when the program exits. That means you may not see the messages you have coded until long after the event
- You should use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to parse CSV data instead of relying on `split`
- You can *interpolate* variables into a double-quoted string. That avoids the use of several concatenation operators and makes the intention clearer
- Your `open` is near-perfect - an unusual thing - because you correctly use the three-parameter form of `open` as well as testing whether it succeeded and putting `$!` in the `die` string. However you should also always use a lexical file handle as well instead of the old-fashioned global ones
- You don't `chomp` the lines you read from the input, so the last field will have a trailing newline. Using `Text::CSV` avoids the need for this
- You use indices 1 through 4 of the data split from the input record. Perl indices start at zero, so that means you are droppping the first field. Is that correct?
- Similarly you are inserting fields 1 and 2, which appear to be `subject` and `date`, into fields called `subject` and `weight`. It seems unlikely that this can be right
- You should `prepare` your SQL statements, use placeholders, and provide the actual data in an `execute` call
- You seem to diagnose the data read from the file ("No Weight") but insert the data into the database anyway. This may be correct but it seems unlikely

Here is a version of your program that includes these amendments. I hope it is of use to you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Text::CSV;
use IO::Handle;

STDOUT->autoflush;

# MySQL config variables
my $host = "localhost";
my $user = "someuser";
my $pw   = "somepassword";

my $database = "test";
my $dsn      = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw)
    or die "Can't connect to the DB: $DBI::errstr\n";

print "Connected to DB!\n";

my $filename = "/home/jonathan/dep/csv/linux_datetime_test_4.26.13_.csv";

open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

$csv->getline($fh) for 1, 2;  # Drop header lines

my $insert_datetime_stamp = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO datetime_stamp (subject, date, time, weight) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)' );
my $insert_subj_weight = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO subj_weight (subject, weight) VALUES(?, ?)' );

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {

    if (length($row->[4]) < 10) {
        print qq{Invalid weight: "$row->[4]"\n};
    }
    else {
        #insert the data into the db
        print "insert into datetime_stamp\n";
        $insert_datetime_stamp->execute(@$row[1..4]);
        $insert_subj_weight->execute(@$row[1,4]);
    }
}
```